# Run-time error '3061' Too few parameters. Expected 1

Tags: ms-access, vba

Keep getting a run-time error 3061 which the following script in Acces.  Debugger reports a problem with last line but for the life of me I cannot see what the issue is.  Any assistance greatly appreciated.

```
Dim db As Database

Dim salers As DAO.Recordset 'Sale

Set db = CurrentDb

Dim saleQuery As String

saleQuery = "SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE salesID = " & Me.saleID.Value & ";"

Set salers = db.OpenRecordset(saleQuery)
```

Comment: what datatype is salesID ?? Does salesID have a value?

Comment: Use `Debug.Print saleQuery` to read the constructed SQL statement.

Comment: salesID is a Long Integer AutoNumber

Answer (score 0):

This error almost always means something is miss-spelled, or doesn't exist. So, ensure that `Sales` and `salesID` exist and are spelled properly in the query.

If that is OK, look at `Me.saleID.Value`. If this is a string, the query will have enclose the value in quotes:

```
saleQuery = "SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE salesID = '" & Me.saleID.Value & "';"
```

Note the ' around the saleID value.

Comment: Tried adding the ' around saleID value after reading other posts but alas this did not resolve. ........Oh No..........After looking at this for hours I have just spotted that I have salesID not saleID.  Thanks @kismert will go slap myself (hard) several times over.